# MySQL Java syntax error

Tags: java, mysql

Trying to figure out what the error is in this java code.

```
The SQLException reads: " You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to 
use near 'order (item_quantity, customer_id, product_id) VALUES (5, 191, 31)'
```

The order table looks like

```
order_id int pk ai <br>
item_quantity <br>
customer_id int <br>
product_id int <br>
```

And the function that inserts is:

```
public void createOrder(int productQuantity, int customerId, int productId) throws SQLException {

    sql = "INSERT INTO order (item_quantity, customer_id, product_id) VALUES (" + productQuantity + ", " + customerId + ", " + productId + ")";
    try {
        int a = stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
        if (a == 1) {
            System.out.println("Order Added");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Order Failed");
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, can't seem to figure this out.

Comment: Could you please backtick the `order`?

Comment: [ORDER is a reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/keywords.html). Write `'Order'` instead `order`.

Comment: Unrelated to this specific problem, but as _soon_ as you start getting comfortable with this way of doing SQL, you should start looking into PreparedStatements. They offer you greater security (if your `int` args were Strings, I would immediately be wondering about a SQL injection attack).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enclose the **order** (table name) by backtick
like below:

```
INSERT INTO `order` (item_quantity, customer_id, product_id) VALUES...
```

**Note:**

The backticks help you from accidentally using a name that is a reserved word in SQL for example. Take a table named "where", it's a stupid name for a table I agree, but if you wrap it in backticks it will work fine

Comment: could you print the `sql` variable and share the result?

Comment: sql variable:INSERT INTO 'order' (item_quantity, customer_id, product_id) VALUES (3, 211, 31)

Comment: Probably you are not using backtick. Instead you used single quote.